# Is it acceptable that mastic was applied as a blob on the back of tiles in shower stall?

Tags: shower, tile

We recently had a new bathroom built in basement. The tile job is suspicious to say the least ( based on watching too many home improvement shows). The tiles were put on walls not by buttering evenly the tile or the wall; instead he used a blob of mastic and stuck tiles on wall and in turn there are gaps behind the tiles. Is this even acceptable technically? What are my risk? When we asked... he said that he was doing so to ensure even layout?

Comment: The risk is that a bump against an unsupported tile will crack the corner off. I'd insist that the job be redone according to the tile manufacturer's requirement.

Comment: Mastic or thinset?  If it’s in the shower mastic shouldn’t used at all.

Answer (score 2):

The mastic should have been put on with a notched trowel. A notched trowel is the industry standard and the best way to ensure the tile will be secure and seat at a uniform level. I would not want a hack job in my bathroom, I hope a backer board was used or at least green board.

Comment: Thank you Ed; yes backer board was used ... but the trowel was not used in the traditional sense